# Disk Management shows incorrect volume size

Tags: windows, partitioning, windows-server-2008-r2, disk-management

Earlier I shrunk drive C using Disk Management but ran into "The parameter is incorrect" error. I now have the following situation:

According to the top pane in the following screenshot, Disk 0 (which hosts C: and System Reserved) should have [272.25GB - 156.25GB - 100MB = 115.9GB](https://www.google.com/search?q=272.25GB%20-%20156.25GB%20-%20100MB) available:

[image: diskmgmt.msc screenshot]

But notice that volume C is reported as having 156.25GB in the top pane but 275.15GB in bottom. And I am unable to find the missing space. Where is the missing space and how do I get it back?

Comment: Backup Disk0 to disk D. Clean Disk 0. Create partition and restore backup.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found matching symptoms and the solution here:

[Windows Server 2008 – Extend System Volume Error 'The parameter is incorrect'](http://www.jonathanmedd.net/2010/10/windows-server-2008-extend-system-volume-error-the-parameter-is-incorrect.html)

> It's as simple as
>
> ```
> DISKPART> select volume #
> ```
>
> where # is the number of the affected volume which can be found with
>   `list volume`.
>
> ```
> DISKPART> extend filesystem
> ```
>
> Now the file system size should match the new partition size.

Comment: This worked on a Windows 10 machine.  In my case Linux gparted froze during a partition expansion operation and was aborted by powering down the live cd session.  After chkdsk corrected issues found the drive size reporting mismatch was the last unsolved puzzle which this resolved.